# ZF2 - How to handle n to n relations in forms and models without Doctrine

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to know what is the best way to handle relations between models in ZF2.

My example is rather simple:

- a 'News' table with id, title, text, date fields
- a 'Keywords' table with id, label, visibility
- a relation table to link news and keywords (n to n relations)

When I create a news with my form, I want to select 0,1 or several keywords. Populating the multicheckboxes field is not a problem but when I want to save my item, how should I do it ?

I mean, I already have my models and entities ready but I don't know what to change to handle property the fact that my news have keywords linked to it.

- Should I hydrate a 'keywords' property in my 'News' entity that will get the related keywords from the table ?
- Should I manage the relations between my News and Keywords in my NewsModel (an abstract table gateway class) ?

Hope my explanations are clear.

Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I have same functionality in my project. Basicly i create form class which adds the diferent fieldsets. These fieldsets implements the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface to have acces to doctrine object manager. For this to work, the instance of the form in the controller became slightly different. First we have to configrue the factory, for example like that: add this fucntion to module.php

```
public function getFormElementConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'News' => function() {
                return new \Admin\Form\News\CreateNews();
            },
        )
    );
}
```

After that, i create the standard form class CreateNews.php and this class can be instantiate in controllers with the service locator through FormElementManager. This is in my controller:

```
$sl = $this->getServiceLocator();
$form = $sl->get('FormElementManager')->get($this->formName);
$form->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($em, $this->repository))->bind($object);
```

Back in the form class instead of adding inputs here i add diferent fieldset. In this fieldset i add the form elelemts. So in my CreateNews.php

```
namespace Admin\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as ClassMethodsHydrator;

class CreateNews extends Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAttributes(array(
            'method' => 'post',
            'class'  => 'custom horizontal-form',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ));

        $this
            ->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
            ->setInputFilter(new InputFilter());

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'news',
            'type' => 'Admin\Form\NewsFieldset',
            'options' => array(
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
            'name' => 'csrf'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Send',
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm'
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

This is the NewsFieldset.php

```
namespace Admin\Form;

use Application\Entity\Keyword;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods as ClassMethodsHydrator;

class NewsFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator
     */
    protected $serviceLocator;


    /**
     * @param ServiceLocatorInterface $sl
     */
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $sl;
    }

    /**
     * @return ServiceLocatorInterface
     */
    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    public function getObjectManager()
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    }

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethodsHydrator(false))
            ->setObject(new Keyword());

        //.. Add dif inputs here

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox',
            'name' => 'keywords',
            'options' => array(
                'object_manager' => $this->getObjectManager(),
                'target_class' => 'Application\Entity\Keywords',
                'property' => 'lable',
                'is_method' => true,
                'find_method' => array(
                    'name' => 'findAll',
                ),
            ),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            // ... inputfilter
        );
        }
    }
```

So what i have done. I create instance of my form with FormElementManager instead of ordinary way. Then in my form i add the fieldset for base form elements (news form) and in this fieldset i add Doctrine ObjectMultiCheckbox. This element needs the object manager and thats why we implement the service locator interface. To work this, the fileset should implement the init() method instead of __construct() method

At last, in my entities only two additions are needed. Add the public functions addKeywords() and removeKeywords()

```
 /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $keywords
     */
    public function addKeywords(ArrayCollection $keywords)
    {
        foreach ($keywordsas $keyword) {
            $this->keywords->add($keyword);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $keywords
     */
    public function removeKeywords(ArrayCollection $keywords)
    {
        foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
            $this->keywords->removeElement($keywords);
        }
    }
```

When submiting the form, doctrine takes care for hydrating the object properly.